# When is $CAC^{-1}$ bounded for $C$ Hilbert-Schmidt?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I came across the following question:
Given a self-adjoint, positive definite Hilbert-Schmidt operator $C$ and a self-adjoint, bounded and positive operator $A$ - both acting on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ - is then
$$
B = CAC^{-1}
$$
a bounded operator on $\mathcal H$, too? If not, which requirements on $A$ would guarantee the boundedness of $B$ (except $A$ being the identity)?

Comment: Here is a counterexample: take $H$ generated by two orthogonal sequence $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, $A$ the operator $2*Id$ + the operator which switch $a_n$ and $b_n$ for all $n$, and $C$ the operator which acts on $a_n$ by multiplication by $1/n$ and on $b_n$ by multiplication by $1/n^2$.

then $(C A C^{-1}) (b_n)=n.b_n$

Generalizing this idea you can construct counterexample for a very large class of $A$. (for example for any operator which have two infinite dimensional disjoint spectral projection...)

Comment: @SimonHenry Why not leave this as an answer?

Comment: Because the question was "Which requirements on A..." and I have no idea on if and how my counterexample really allow to says something about that ? (and because I think that the answer is "this is true for almost no $A$" and I was hoping that someone would prove this)

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer (but I am not entitled) since it is merely a reformulation of your condition albeit in a way which may shed some light.  By the spectral theorem, we can assume that $C$ is the operation of multiplication by an $\ell^2$ sequence $(x_n)$ on $\ell^2$.  Then the condition is that the operator $A$  also act continuously on the weighted $\ell^2$ space consisting of those sequences $(y_n)$ for which $\sum \left (\frac { y_n}{x_n}\right )^2<\infty$.